# How can i execute a javascript when a user clicks a button

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, javascript

I am creating an extension for Chrome. I want to execute a script when the user clicks a button. Here is the code i currently have in my html file

```
<input type="button" id ="button" onclick='notEmpty()' value="Play"/>
```

The `notEmpty()` is in a javascript (.js) file. How can I execute another script in the `notEmpty()` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use functions that are located in another file, you would need to import those files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/script.js"></script>
```

But, in Google Chrome Extensions, if you want to "execute" a script when you click on a button (from an extension page), you can use the [chrome.tabs.executeScript](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript) functionality

```
// Run that script on the current tab. The first argument is the tab id.
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: '/path/to/script.js'});
```

It all depends on your scenario, when you "executeScript" as shown above, it will inject a [content script](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html) into that DOM. If you import that script, you will just use those functionality in the current DOM (in that case the extension page, not the tab).

Hope that helped!

Answer (score 3):

I have not written an extension for chrome but for typical javascript you can do one of the following.

```
<script type="text\javascript">
   function notEmpty()
   {
       someOtherFunction();
   }
</script>
```

or

```
<input type="button" id ="button" onclick='notEmpty(); someOtherFunction();' value="Play"/>
```